# I need to find out an element which has a definite CSS style for eg. height and width?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to find out an element which has a definite CSS style for eg.  a div having height:100px and width:100px?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve? Code examples are also always welcome :)

Comment: Try to do some research before asking a question StackOverflow. Start with [the site of jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that, use more specific selector as ID or CLASS. If for some reason you still need to search for that, you could use `.filter()` method:

```
var targetedDIVs = $('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).height() === 100 && $(this).width() === 100
});
```

you could wish to use instead `outerHeight(|true])` or `innerHeight()` {the same for width}

But this will return all the DIVs with computed style height and width equal to 100px, not just DIVs with specific style setted in CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do the trick

```
var $elems = $('*').filter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.css('width') == "100px" && $this.css('height') == "100px";
});
```